# Animated gif doesn't play properly during transforms in Chrome and Firefox, works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, animated-gif

I have an animated gif that follows mouse cursor and rotates slightly as it chases the mouse using simple javascript and jquery.  This works perfectly fine in IE11, but in Chrome (v 43.0.2) and Firefox (v39.0) the animated gif does not play or just jitters erratically.  Fiddle of what I'm doing:

```js
// follow mouse 
var $mouseX = 0, $mouseY = 0;
var $xp = 0, $yp =0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  $mouseX = e.pageX;
  $mouseY = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();    
});

var $loop = setInterval(function(){
  var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var pos;
  $xp += (($mouseX - $xp)/50);
  $yp += (($mouseY - $yp)/50);
  var deg = 0;
  var hozDiff = Math.floor($mouseX - $xp);
  var maxAngle = 45;

  if (hozDiff > 0){
    $("#kirby").attr('src', 'http://media.giphy.com/media/6Uj6lFq4KWDQY/giphy.gif');
    if (hozDiff < maxAngle) deg = hozDiff;
    else deg = maxAngle;
  }
  else {
    $("#kirby").attr('src', 'http://media.giphy.com/media/6Uj6lFq4KWDQY/giphy.gif');
    if (hozDiff > -maxAngle) deg = hozDiff;
    else deg = -maxAngle;
  }

  $("#kirby").css({left:$xp +'px', top:$yp +'px',
    position:'fixed',
    'transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)'
  });
}, 30);
```

```html
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <body>

    <img id="kirby" src="http://media.giphy.com/media/6Uj6lFq4KWDQY/giphy.gif"/>

  </body>
```

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue. Not much you can do about that other than try to explain to people that IE has actually gotten better since version 6...

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get around this issue?

Comment: Well, I suppose technically since the affected browsers are, I believe, open-source, you could figure out and fix the issue yourself and submit it to be patched in, but that's probably a colossal waste of time. I can only really suggest you try using a canvas and/or an animated sprite rather than a gif.